# Is IKVM being properly bundled with Mono releases?

Tags: linux, macos, mono, fedora, ikvm

> [IKVM is fully supported by Mono and its part of the standard Mono package distribution.](http://www.mono-project.com/Java)

Downloaded [Mono MRE installer for Mac](http://download.mono-project.com/archive/3.2.3/macos-10-x86/MonoFramework-MRE-3.2.3.macos10.xamarin.x86.pkg).
After installation I have no ikvm command. I have:

```
Ashen:Temp dan$ find /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/ -name "*ikvm*"
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework//Versions/2.10.11/lib/libikvm-native.dylib
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework//Versions/2.10.11/lib/libikvm-native.dylib.dSYM
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework//Versions/2.10.11/lib/libikvm-native.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/libikvm-native.dylib
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework//Versions/2.10.11/lib/libikvm-native.la
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework//Versions/3.2.3/lib/libikvm-native.dylib
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework//Versions/3.2.3/lib/libikvm-native.dylib.dSYM
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework//Versions/3.2.3/lib/libikvm-native.dylib.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/libikvm-native.dylib
```

No executables.

On Fedora:

```
sudo yum install monodevelop
ikvm
-bash: ikvm: command not found
```

[Windows](http://download.mono-project.com/archive/3.2.3/windows-installer/mono-3.2.3-gtksharp-2.12.11-win32-0.exe) does have an ikvm.bat in /bin and an executable in /lib/ikvm.

Is it possible to use IKVM on Mac or Linux with Mono?

Thanks, Dan.

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI, but MonoDevelop is not Mono, so installing that package won't include IKVM. I suspect that IKVM is bundled separately on Linux because Linux distros typically split stuff into dozens of packages.

On Mac, try installing the MDK instead of the MRE.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the MDK did not include IKVM either.

Comment: If it's not in the MDK, then it's just not included in the Mono packages for Mac I guess. You'll probably have to build it yourself.